# Arduino to Sim900 wiring

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, sim900

I need your help. I am newbie in here 
I want to create communication between arduino and sim900 gsm/gprs module, but I am still confuse about the wiring

there are two type wirings in sim900 to arduino, hardware serial wiring and software serial wiring. Which one do i have to use ? 
Hardware serial wiring or software serial wiring

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the sim900 has an I2C interface.  If you are using an Arudino-Uno, the hardware serial port it used to communicate to your PC, therefore, I would use the I2C interface.  See the "Wire" https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire library for examples.

Comment: so.. i have to use software serial to make communication between arduino-uno and sim900, right ??

Comment: The sim900 seems to have a choice of different interfaces.  I was suggesting that you use the I2C instead of the normal uart-serial interface.

Answer (score 0):

On SIM900, use the Pins named TXD and RXD to connect to Digital Input Pins on Arduino.